# error con conexion->exec() en php: Call to a member function exec() on null

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de guardar unos datos utilizando el siguiente código...

```
<?php 

class conexion{

    private $servidor="localhost";
    private $usuario="root";
    private $password="";
    private $namedb="proyecto";
    private $conexion;

    public function __construct(){

        try{

            $this->conexion= new PDO("mysql:host=$this->servidor;dbname=proyecto",$this->usuario,$this->password);
            $this->conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            
            //echo "Conexion correcta!";

        }catch(PDOException $e){

            return "Falla de conexion".$e;

        }

    }

    public function ejecutar($sql){

        $this->conexion->exec($sql);
        return $this->conexion->lastInsertId();

    }

} ?>
```

luego utilizo esta clase de la siguiente forma para pasarle la sentencia junto con lo que quiero guardar:

```
<?php include("cabecera.php"); 
include("conexion.php"); 


$objConexion= new conexion();

$sql="INSERT INTO `proyecto` (`id`, `nombre`, `imagen`, `descripcion`) VALUES (NULL, 'proyecto 3', 'imagen.jpg', 'Lo que sea, solo es una prueba.');";

$objConexion->ejecutar($sql); ?>
```

pero al ejecutar el segmento de código anterior me muestra el siguiente error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function exec() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ejercicios\portafolio\conexion.php:30 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Ejercicios\portafolio\galeria.php(9): conexion->ejecutar('INSERT INTO `pr...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ejercicios\portafolio\conexion.php on line 30

El archivo conexion.php contiene la clase del segmento de codigo incial y galeria.php contiene el segundo segemento de codigo, no logro identificar en que estoy mal...

Comment: Hay una mezcla extraña de distintos tipos de comillas y acentos cuando defines tu consulta. Yo reemplazaría todos los ` por '. Por otro lado, ¿estás seguro de que la conexión a la base de datos se está haciendo correctamente? Puedes ejecutar alguna query de prueba justo despues de instanciar $this->conexion para ver si funciona.

Comment: Es un error de sintaxis. El problema esta en el método `__construct`, mas precisamente en `"mysql:host=$this->servidor;dbname=proyecto"`, debería ser: `"mysql:host=".$this->servidor.";dbname=".$this->namedb`> PD: fijate que estas mezclando ingles y español.

Comment: Efectivamente, un error de sintaxis, muchas gracias por sus comentarios!